# Why Won't Split Recognize Pipes Even with "\\|"?

Tags: java, split, java.util.scanner

We're trying to read a file and then split by pipe. The code is reading the file, but not recognizing the pipe. For example, the line of the file says Cola|0, and after the split to array, we're getting an out of bounds exception for array[1]. That should definitely exist if the line was split properly.

When we had an if(line.contains"\|"), it returned true every time even though there were pipes in the lines. We tried using nextInt for our while instead of nextLine, but it immediately returned false and ended the while (which it shouldn't have done because there are definitely numbers).

We also tried using substring with indexOf("\|")+1 to the end, and it still did not work. Why is it not catching the pipe?

```
try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        if (!line.contains("$")) {
            for (String item : productsSold.keySet()) {
                String[] productDetails = line.split("\\|");
                productsSold.put(item, Integer.parseInt(productDetails[1]));
```

Cola|0 should make the second line of the array 0. Instead we're getting an out of bounds exception for the array.

Comment: Did you try to print `line`? What does it contain? Also, does _every_ line contain a `|`? `"Cola|0".split("\\|")` [works just as expected](https://tio.run/##LYyxDoIwFEVn@IqmUzvYuDMZZydGcXiCIa@2tOl7kBDh22sNTjf3npNrYYGTHd4ZfQyJhS3dzIzOXFKClZoc56fDXvQOiMQNcBKfuvqPxMAlloCD8AWplhNO4/0hII2kf2bVrsQvb8LMJhbIblLHteFw6Epeg4PtLA1Fh6xk121Sa93U1V7vOX8B).

Comment: When using `indexOf` and `contains`, there is no need to escape a pipe: `indexOf("|")` and `contains("|")` are what you would use.

Comment: @Ivar, there are pipes in most lines. I think the location of the for each loop in regards to the line instantiation caused the problem with split and the out of bounds exception.

Comment: @AndyTurner, thanks! We used contains("|") successfully, and it helped clean up a hole in our if-statement's logic!

Answer (score -1):

I believe, the location of the foreach loop was at fault. It kept attempting to split the same line, which eventually resulted in an array that did not have an index at 1.

Comment: That's a simple programming error, and is of no use to anyone else, since they'd be unlikely to even find this question/answer. so just delete the question, please.